# How to watch an array for changes in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I basically want the equivalent to binding to 'add' and 'remove' events in Backbone's Collections. I see basically no way of doing this in AngularJS, and the current workaround we've settled for is `$watch()`ing the array's `length` and manually diffing/recalculating the whole thing. Is this really what the cool kids do?

*Edit*: Specifically, watching the array's length means I don't easily know which element has been changed, I need to manually "diff".

Comment: Is there anything specific you wish to do? What is wrong with $watching the array's length?

Comment: @ganaraj Edited, I just want to know which element got changed

Comment: Angular's data binding does work like events; what you need to do is to change the way you are thinking. Why do you actually need to know that?

Comment: @ganaraj watching length is not safe. There can be multiple changes in the array being watched in the same digest cycle, making the watcher not fire at all. e.g. `array.splice(0,1,"hello")`

Comment: @fastreload e.g. I have a list of stuff (say, todos) and the server is waiting to receive notifications of which were deleted/added

Comment: You can just create `add` and `remove` functions in the controller which does that and pushes to array then. It is almost always a good idea to not reach functions directly from the `view`. It should not contain any business logic.

Answer (score 37):

I think using [`$watch`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch) is a good solution, but [`$watchCollection`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24watchCollection) can be better for you. [`$watchCollection`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24watchCollection) doesn't perform deep comparison and just watchs for array modification like insert, delete or sort (**not item update**).

For exemple, if you want to keep an attribut `order` synchronize with the array order :

```
$scope.sortableItems = [
    {order: 1, text: 'foo'},
    {order: 2, text: 'bar'},
    {order: 3, text: 'baz'}
];

$scope.$watchCollection('sortableItems', function(newCol, oldCol, scope) {
    for (var index in newCol) {
        var item = newCol[index];
        item.order = parseInt(index) + 1;
    }
});
```

But for your problem, I do not know if there is a better solution than manually browse the array to identify the change.

Answer (score 12):

The way to watch an array in Angular is  `$watch(array, function(){} ,true)`

Comment: That is a deep watch. You probably dont need that in most of the cases.

Comment: @Jason Als: Thanks, but that doesn't tell me which element has been removed/added. I edited the question to make that clearer :)

Comment: @ganaraj actually you do, see my comment on op's question

Answer (score 3):

I would create child scopes and watch them individually.
here is an example:

```
$scope.myCollection = [];
var addChild = function()
{
  var Child = $scope.$new();
  Child.name = 'Your Name here';

  Child.$watch('name', function(newValue) {
     // .... do something when the attribute 'name' is changed ...
  });

  Child.$on('$destroy', function() {
    //... do something when this child gets destroyed 
  });


  $scope.myCollection.push(Child); // add the child to collection array

};

// Pass the item to this method as parameter, 
// do it within an ngRepeat of the collection in your views 
$scope.deleteButtonClicked = function(item)
{
  var index = $scope.myCollection.indexOf(item); //gets the item index
  delete $scope.myCollection[index]; // removes the item on the array
  item.$destroy(); // destroys the original items
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please tell more about your usecase. One of the solutions of tracking element persistance is using ngRepeat directive with custom directive that listening element's $destroy event:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" on-delete="doSomething(item)">

angular.module("app").directive("onDelete", function() {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.on("$destroy", function () {
                scope.$eval(attrs.onDelete);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: That's nice but I just don't feel like making my MVC bind to the elements in the view to know when something in my model has changed is the right way to go...?

Comment: Yes. Another solution is creating Model and Collection classes like in Backbone.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the solution is to create the collection class ( like backbone does ) and you can hook into events pretty easily as well.

The solution I have done here isnt really comprehensive, but should give you a general guidance on how this could be done perhaps.

http://beta.plnkr.co/edit/dGJFDhf9p5KJqeUfcTys?p=preview